# How to "push" audio stream through the phone to the caller without using the phone's speaker

Tags: android, audio-streaming

I am very new to Android and would like to know the libraries / classes / API, if any, which can be used to stream audio to the caller without using the phone's speaker.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i am not sure i understand. how can you stream and play audio if not from the speaker? or is this some streaming operation that needs to happen in the background?

Comment: @sriram: I believe that the way we speak into the microphone, and it go to the listener.. Is there any way in which we can directly write something into (may be) the microphone buffer and eventually push this written content to the caller? I hope I am more clear now..

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be difficult to do as answered here [Need to play audio to the caller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319949/need-to-play-audio-to-the-caller)